# В чем заключается неэффективность моего алгоритма?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеется вот такая задача:

Дано натуральное число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^18). Найдите количество пар неотрицательных целых чисел (x, y), удовлетворяющих соотношению x^2 + y^3 = n.
В ответе укажите одно число – количество пар.

Ограничение по времени для Python - 5 секунд, по памяти - 256 мб.
Для других языков 1 секунда, память - 64 мб.

Вот код:

```
n, count = int(input()), 0

def X_square(N):
    array = []
    for i in range(N + 1):
        fig = i ** 2
        if fig <= N:
            array.append(fig)
        else:
            break
    return array


def N_sub_Y_cube(N):
    for j in range(N + 1):
        fig = j ** 3
        if fig <= N:
            yield N - fig
        else:
            break


def binary_search(elem, array):
    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = len(array) - 1
# count = 0

    while lower_bound <= upper_bound:
        center = (lower_bound + upper_bound) // 2
        if elem == array[center]:
            # count += 1
            return elem
        elif elem < array[center]:
            upper_bound = center - 1
        elif elem > array[center]:
            lower_bound = center + 1
    return -1


for i in N_sub_Y_cube(n):
    if binary_search(i, X_square(n)) == -1:
        continue
    else:
        count +=1
print(count)
```

*Для 10^9 работает вполне нормально, но потом упирается в ограничение по времени (для 11 значного числа уже считает долго). И правильно ли я понимаю, что сложность О(nlogn)?*

Comment: Идите по y от 1 до 10^6 (корень кубический из n), вычисляйте x, убеждайтесь, что это целое или нет...

Comment: Я не уверен, но кажется у вас сложность `n^(5/6)*log(n)`, вы ее можете сократить до `n^(1/3) * log(n)`, если вынесете X_square(n) из цикла.

Comment: Если вы извлекаете корень квадратный из значения `double` и это значение полный квадрат, то корень будет извлечён точно. Это гарантия из стандарта [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Так что извлекайте корень, проверяйте что он целый, возводите его обратно в квадрат (тоже точная операция) и проверяйте что получили исходное число. Бинарный поиск тут лишний.

Answer (score 4):

Идите по y от 1 до 10^6 (корень кубический из n), вычисляйте x, убеждайтесь, что это целое или нет... Примерно так (в Python могу и ошибиться...)

```
import math

n, count = int(input()), 0

for y in range(n + 1):
    x = n - y * y * y
    if x < 0:
        break
    z = int(math.sqrt(x))
    if z * z == x:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: @EzikBro OK, исправил.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо; не могли бы вы исправить код в ответе? Я в Python не очень; вот если бы это был С++...

Comment: Поправил. Замечу что этот алгоритм не специфичен для Python. На C++ всё было бы то самое.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо! Да, поэтому я и могу написать алгоритм, а вот реализацию - не очень. Например, я бы написал по привычке `&&` :)